# When i try to push my rails app on heroku, the assets precompile don't work

Tags: git, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I learn rails since two weeks and i want to push to heroku my project but i try since 2 days and i have the same error when i do `$git push gossip-project master` :

```
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb:24:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/cache.rb:60:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/cache.rb:60:in `lookup_store'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:67:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.2/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_3590ca37744ff815b68e359812cf998d/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to guarded-river-63918.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/guarded-river-63918.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/guarded-river-63918.git'
```

I tried all the possibilities i seen on differents forum but that doesn't work. But i can push a new rails app on heroku without problem. I don't know what's the problem. Thanks you for your help and i am sorry for my very bad english, i don't speak english.
Nils

Comment: If someone want to see my app https://github.com/Nils-Lopez/gossip_project

Comment: it says bootstrap in the error log, how do you import bootstrap into the project?

Comment: In layout/application.rb i have a <link> to bootstrap